# Pushing data in array inside for loop

Tags: javascript

Thanks in advance, i am trying to add request response in promises array inside for loop, currently `CURRENCIES` array have two values and forloop working good iterating for two times, but inside push i am unable to get value of `CURRENCIES` array at current index.

```
let promises = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < CURRENCIES.length; i++) {
        const api = 'https://api.etherscan.io/api';
        promises.push(
            axios.get(api, {
                params: {
                    module: 'account', action: 'txlist',
                    address: '0x.........',
                    sort: 'asc', apikey: 'R6...........'
                }
            }).then((response) => {
                console.log(CURRENCIES[i])
                var data = {};
                data[CURRENCIES[i]] = response.data.result
                transactionsHistory.push(data);
            })
        )
    }
```

In `console.log` for `CURRENCIES[i]` i always have `undefined`

Comment: use `let` instead of `var`.

Comment: you made my day thanks :)

Comment: what exactly do you need to push inside promises?

Answer (score 0):

The value of `i` is changing by the time the Promise resolves and you try to use it in the `then` function. You can be more explicit with it like this:

```
let promises = [];
for (var i = 0; i < CURRENCIES.length; i++) {
  const api = "https://api.etherscan.io/api";
  // setting a variable within the loop will make it valid within the scope.
  const currency = CURRENICES[i];
  promises.push(
    axios
      .get(api, {
        params: {
          module: "account",
          action: "txlist",
          address: "0x.........",
          sort: "asc",
          apikey: "R6..........."
        }
      })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(currency);
        var data = {};
        data[currency] = response.data.result;
        transactionsHistory.push(data);
      })
  );
}
```

The problem was that you were using `var` which makes it a kind of global variable at the top level scope.  Changing to `let` would make its scope more localized and should solve the problem too, but I like using a different variable within the loop to be more clear what is being used.